# Error on Deploying FastAPI application to Azure Web App service

Tags: python, azure, github, deployment, fastapi

After completing the code i tries to deploy my app in azure and it is failing deployment from last 3 days. I still don't know what is error. So, i need help what is the error. So, my app get successfully deploy.

Observations:

1. From Github actions

```
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Fetching changes.
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/d9b5354b-a273-4901-9ec7-2349e7950810.zip (32.46 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
App Service Application URL: https://healix-backend.azurewebsites.net
```

**then i click the url getting this error **

```html
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.
```

2. From the logs

app log :

[image]

I click the app logs

temp log :

[image]

```
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
Done in 164 sec(s).
Compressing content of directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
```

seems fine to me, if need all the logs let me know

click the temp log part

[image]

```
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/d9b5354b-a273-4901-9ec7-2349e7950810.zip (32.46 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
```

seem fine to me

When click on last one send me to github

[image]

There text ask me to check the logs which i did already.

From last three days, I am looking for an error. What is the error I have.

**Note:**
By the way code work fine locally.

I am excepted to get information about the error or guidence to deploy my fatapi api to azure.

Sucess:

```
{
    "message": "Backend Client for the project"
}
```

[Source Code link](https://github.com/DeepeshKalura/textToSpeechForHealthCareAPI)

Over view of the app:

[image]

Comment: there is another approach you can also try to deploy through azure container registry.

Answer (score 0):

> Deploying FastAPI application to Azure Web App service

There is another approach for deploy the fastapi application through container registry by using visual studio code.

I have created sample fastapi application and deployed to azure web application through container registry.

I have created sample fastapi application by using below code:

**fastapi code:**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, query_param: str = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "query_param": query_param}
```

`pip install fastapi uvicorn` package has been installed.
the above fastapi application ran successfully. check below:
[image]

I have added docker file in the application directory.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run the application using Uvicorn
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

**requirement.txt:**

```
fastapi==0.70.0
uvicorn==0.15.0
```

By using below commands I have successfully build and run the application in docker. check below:

```
docker build -t fastapi-app .
docker run -p 8000:8000 fastapi-app
```

[image]
[image]

By using below commands I am able to login container registry and pushed.

```
docker tag fastapi-app <ACR login server>/fastapi-app:latest
docker login <ACR login server> -u <username> -p <password>
docker push <ACR login server>/fastapi-app:latest
```

Get the details of username and password of container registry by follow below step:

[image]

while creating the web app select publish as Docker container and operating system as Linux and follow like below:

[image]

The web app is successfully deployed. check below:

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried again, with the exact method you suggested but I get the same result.  Mention below
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources. 
Since, I uploaded code into docker hub too, if you want you can try running that. https://hub.docker.com/r/deepeshkalura/fastapi-healix

Comment: Can you refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78000580/21525734) for that particular issue.