# deploy flask python on azure webapp

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have `app.py` flask that I am trying to deploy to **Azure web app** to use as an API instead of localhost I have all the code on a github repo with requirements.txt text file as well

what I get when I click on the deployment link is this error:

```
:( Application Error

If you are the application administrator, you can access the [diagnostic resources](https://ku-backend-statging.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors).
```

I tried deploying from vs code same error

And I tried multiple time on azure portal nothing happens even the ssh will be closed when ssh is turned on from the settings

Comment: Please share your GitHub repository link.

Answer (score 1):

> :( Application Error

To know the exact error, enable ***Application Logging*** in `App Service=>Monitoring=>App Service Logs` and check the logs in **Log Stream**.

I have cloned a basic flask application from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-flask-webapp-quickstart).

- Create and activate Virtual environment before running the application locally

```
py -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

**Local response:**

[image]

[image]

- Create a Linux Azure App Service with Python 3.11 as runtime stack.
- ***Add below mentioned Application Settings  in the App Service=>Settings=>Environment Variables=>Application Settings***:

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
WEBSITES_PORT=<Port_number>
```

- Deployed the application using VSCode:

[image]

- Able to browse the deployed flask application successfully.

[image]

- I could also deploy the flask application using GitHub actions.

**References:**

[Deploy a Python (Django or Flask) web app to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli)

Comment: Yes I have tried this demo app and it worked fine however I have routs like /search or /savetodb that I cant use 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Can you share your repository link, so that I can try and check the issue.

Comment: I am afraid I can't do that since it contains confidential information... I only can share the /search route setup here... nvm the code I provided is 199 chars too long

Comment: '''def search_index(prompt, query_vector):
    results = client.search(prompt,include_total_count=False,query_type='semantic',
                                query_language="ar-kw",  select=select_fields,top=3, semantic_configuration_name="default" )
    # results = client.search(prompt,include_total_count=False,
    #                             query_language="ar-kw",  select=select_fields,top=5, 
    #                             vector_queries = [RawVectorQuery(vector=query_vector, k=50, fields="embedding_content")])'''

Comment: @app.route('/search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search():
    data = request.get_json()
    query = data['query']
    doc_result = embeddings.embed_documents(query)
    response = search_index(query, doc_result)
    return jsonify(response)